# Parsing a Log File with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, parsing, logfile

I need to write a parser for log file. I'm doing the regular expression but I'm finding some problems.
Here is the first line:

```
s0001 | smich | 02-03-2013 13:55:42 (Tue Mar 2013) | 2
```

This is the entry header and I wrote the regular expression like that 
`r\\d+ (\\| .*){3}` but it doesn't work.

What about the comment line??
"Added a new State interface"
I wrote it so: `(\\w+\\s\\w+:)`

The language is Java.
I want that the program recognizes that this is a entry header.
If it is, then it parses it. With parsing I have no problem but I'm not able to find the right regex for it.

It doesn't work, can you correct them please?

Comment: What language/program is this for?  Regex differs between each.

Comment: If the log file is pipe-delimited (|), wouldn't it be easier to simply split the line on the delimiter?  That's something you can do in pretty much any language - even DOS.

Comment: In addition to what @Daedalus said, you also need to provide a complete line with the comments in place.

Comment: What exacly do you want to select?